# where to put src images in Eclipse web project

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

I am hosting an Eclipse Java web project on Tomcat and I have a .jsp page that should pick up an image as illustrated in the code below. Where should I put this image in my project? in WebContent folder? I did so but the image wasn't loaded -- meaning that the I haven't specified the right path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<body>

    <h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
    <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the first time I've seen both the `java` and `javascript` tags used correctly on the same post. Congrats!

Comment: Its a Java backend project, with a html/jsp frontend. Project is using  Eclipse IDE.

Comment: What platform are you on? Is the filesystem case sensitive? What are the paths to the JSP file and image relative to the root of the project?

Answer (score 0):

Image path should be relative to the path where your jsp is.

Comment: yes, it is in same folder. Then loaded on  HTML page as 
`<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" >` but doesn't load. I am using Chrome browser.

Comment: Because you are viewing your HTML in browser, path should be a relative URL. So, start with a '/'. Try using <img src="/pic_mountain.jpg" >

Answer (score 0):

Store the images in a folder under webcontent for example:

`<img src=("images/image_name.jpg">`